# AMS5812 I2C Sensor Holding I2C3 Bus on STM32F407G-DISC1

Tags: sensors, i2c, stm32f4discovery, pressure

I am trying to interface LCD and AMS5812 Sensor on I2C3 Bus of STM32F407G Discovery board,

But AMS5812 I2C sensor is holding the I2C bus and preventing further scanning STM32F407G Discovery board.

Please advise where i could be wrong ?

Using I2C Speed settings 400000HZ and I2C Speed Mode : Fast

Below is I2C Scanner Code for detecting the connected I2C Devices.

```
/*-[ I2C Bus Scanning ]-*/
         HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t *)StartMSG, sizeof(StartMSG), 10000);
         for(i=1; i<128; i++)
         {
             ret = HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady(&hi2c3, (uint16_t)(i<<1), 3, 5);
             if (ret != HAL_OK) /* No ACK Received At That Address */
             {
                 HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t *)Space, sizeof(Space), 10000);
             }
             else if(ret == HAL_OK)
             {
                 sprintf(Buffer, "0x%X", i);
                 HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t *)Buffer, sizeof(Buffer), 10000);
             }
         }
         HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t *)EndMSG, sizeof(EndMSG), 10000);
         /*--[ Scanning Done ]--*/
         HAL_Delay(1000);
```

AMS5812 sensor is working on 5V and i2c LCD is also working on 5V. i am using 5V to 3V level shifter as below.

first time i2c Scanning code detect lcd address as 0x27 and then blank.

Expected 0x27 and 0x78

[image]

[image]

I have tried using 3.1K pull up resistors but no benefit on both the sides of level shifter.

Please advise where i could be wrong ?

Comment: For starters, you will have to explain what exactly the problem is. What exactly does "holding" mean? Is it stuck low? "preventing further scanning" what does that mean? Is the code stuck in some loop? Or it goes through, but doesn't detect anything? You explained your hardware setup well, but it's unclear what is going on. Your "detect" screenshot is not particularly informative without a little extra information of what happens on the software side. It looks like it goes through but doesn't detect anything anymore. Even what it detected before. Is that right?

Comment: Ideally for I2C Scanner code loops should run and show 0x27 and 0x78. I have written Expected Results should be repeated 0x27 and 0x78 Show healthy I2C Communication. As soon as AMS5812 is attached on i2c Bus, only 1st time 0x27 is shown and then nothin as shown in above picture of teraterm.

Comment: Check the state of I2C bus. Is it stuck? What are the levels? Hardware issues are not ruled out. It would be nice to look at I2C lines with scope or logic analyzer if possible, but for starters even a multimeter reading of bus state should give some info.

Comment: ok will check connecting scope. or will try to use it on different i2c Bus.

Comment: Connecting to another I2C is very unlikely to change anything, but go ahead. This is about gathering information. Check the hardware side, scope the bus before the level shifter, scope the bus after the level shifter, read and decode I2C status register flags.